# PyBluez No Bluetooth Adapter Detected Windows 8.1

Tags: python, bluetooth

So I installed PyBluez wheel through pip and it was working just fine. It discovered devices and services.

Not all of a sudden I receive this error every time I try to do anything with bluetooth:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bluetooth
>>> bluetooth.discover_devices()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 15, in discover_devices
    devices = bt.discover_devices()
IOError: No Bluetooth adapter detected
```

I'm using Python 2.7. 
I'm on Windows 8.1 and have a Toshiba Thinkpad T430u. My laptop definitely has its Bluetooth on.

Comment: PyBluez+Windows == Massive Pain

Comment: Yeah tell me about it. Are there any other libraries for python that utilize Bluetooth?

Comment: so it works again after windows 8.1 decided to re-turn on my bluetooth by itself 0.o ... maybe because I just turned on my phone's bluetooth. Maybe windows rests until it finds a compatible bluetooth device nearby? Throwing shots in the dark here

Comment: lol uh huh ... thats all you can do ... now try and narrow it down through trial and error